# Playing youtube link from site

Tags: php, android, macos, youtube

I have the following php code and I dont know why on Android phones and on Mac it's downloading the Youtube video file instead of playing the video.

```
<?php

$feedURL = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/UCfLFTP1uTuIizynWsZq2nkQ/uploads?max-results=1';
$sxml = simplexml_load_file($feedURL);
$i = 0;
foreach ($sxml->entry as $entry) {
    $media = $entry->children('media', true);
    $watch = (string) $media->group->player->attributes()->url;
    $thumbnail = (string) $media->group->content[0]->attributes()->url;
    ?>
    <iframe width="330" border="0" height="220" style="width: 330px;" src="<?php echo $thumbnail; ?>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>      
    <?php
    $i++;

}
?>
```